# Processing large number of JSON files

Tags: json

I have 200K JSON files, individual files are tiny but number of files are 200K.

I just want to run a SQL Group by query over these files without spending too much effort in using a programming language to parse them.

Elastic Search in my mind but it does require events to be published into it before you can search.

Is there any light weight product that you know I can use which does not require any programming or modelling effort?

Answer (score 0):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) should be able to handle that - if you can grok its syntax